# Why django PermissionRequiredMixin is not working as it intended to be

Tags: django

Here i have got a Django view that should normally redirect me to the Settings.LOGIN_URL if user has not the required permission but the issue is it's always displaying the 403 FORBIDDEN page.
the url defined in Settings.LOGIN_URL is 'accounts/login/'.

```
class LibrairianListView(PermissionRequiredMixin, View):
model = BookInstance
template_name = 'catalog/librairian_list_borrowed.html'
permission_required = 'catalog.can_mark_returned'

def get_queryset(self):
    return BookInstance.objects.filter(status__exact='o').order_by('due_back')

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    print(self.raise_exception)
    context = {}
    context['bookinstance_list'] = self.get_queryset()
    return context

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, self.template_name, self.get_context_data())
```

And i change this to a function based view and everything is working fine, but i wanted to use class base view since this should do the same work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened because the user is logged-in but he does not have `'catalog.can_mark_returned'` permission. This is indented behavior and no need to redirect the user to *login page* since he is already logged-in.

If you still wish to modify the way the permission error handled, override the [**`handle_no_permission()`**--(Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.AccessMixin.handle_no_permission) method